# Different column heights at the same values on the kendo js chart (seriesDefaults - type: "column")?

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

What the parameter should be set in order to achieve the same height? 
The gray columns should be the same height (data2: 25934,25934,25934)
The current code and result is:
Where data1 and data2 is: data1: **6803,14588,25728**, data2: **25934,25934,25934**

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: "1",
                        data: data1,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "2",
                        data: data2
                    }
                ],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value) #"
                    }
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [2019, 2020, 2021]
                }
            });
```

[image]

**Update**: just set max attribute for this. This is a answer:

```
            series: [
                {
                    name: "1",
                    stack: "#= value #",
                    data: data1,
                },
                {

                    name: "2",
                    stack: "#= value #",
        max: data2.max,
                    data: data2
                }
            ],
            valueAxis: {
                max: data2.max,
                labels: {
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value) #"
                }
            },
```

Comment: what do you mean same height if the values are different. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The gray columns should be the same height (data2: 25934,25934,25934).
Now on the graph with the same values, different heights are displayed.

Comment: There's something missing from your code, since by default columns don't stack. Are you looking for [`stack: { type: "100%" }`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.stack#seriesstacktype) ?

Comment: @GaloisGirl put you on the right track